# How to run command on EC2 instance after starting session manager on it using bash script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-systems-manager

I am writing bash script to install missing patches on ec2 instance using session manager.
I can start the session using script but I am not sure how can I run command on it using script?

```
    instanceid = "i-098xxxx"

    echo $instanceid
    echo "instance id"

    # Creating AMI 
    echo "-------------------------------Creation AMI-----------------------------------------"
    aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $instanceid --name "test ami" --description "Delete when 
    testing" --no-reboot --profile xyz

    # Start Session Manager
    aws ssm start-session --target $instanceid --profile xyz

 
    # Command to check for critical security patches and update/install it on ec2 instance
    echo "-------------------------------installing missing patches----------------------------- 
    ------------"
    sudo yum update-minimal --sec-severity=critical,important --bugfix
```

I want to run `sudo yum update-minimal --sec-severity=critical,important --bugfix` command in ec2 instance using script.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Have you considered using the Run Command feature of Systems Manager instead? That's designed for exactly this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) provides an SSH-like connection via a web browser.

However, if you wish to automate the execution of commands on instances, you should use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which can run commands on a single instance or hundreds of instances, and return results from each run.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to using run-command, if for some reason you need to use a session, you can do this by using the `AWS-StartNonInteractiveCommand` document, for example:

```bash
aws ssm start-session \
    --document-name 'AWS-StartNonInteractiveCommand' \
    --parameters '{"command": ["sudo yum -y update amazon-ssm-agent"]}' \
    --target "$instanceid"
```

To see the other parameters accepted by this document, run

```bash
aws ssm describe-document --name AWS-StartNonInteractiveCommand
```

Answer (score -2):

I think AWS Systems Manager is best way to resolve this case. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html