# How to create an executable file with SSM and basic commands on ubuntu

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Hello everyone I would like to ask for your assistance regarding scenario below. using my local ubuntu machine I want to access and create an executable to my AWS Instance machine. I tried to use same commands with my executable file however it doesn't work, but works if I just paste the command on my CLI, it doesn't push thru and stops after "aws ssm start-session" command. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

This is the command I used to access and install my AWS Machine:

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIASHIYHNRJMIE52OP2"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="Zlmki7fOg3XLWYQYRp55mylgiuffCJbsMh0c2upu"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="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"
aws ssm start-session --target  i-0fac71837dd267123
sudo -i
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install curl -y
sudo apt install -y default-jdk

Screenshot:

[File Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsta0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to run command on EC2 instance after starting session manager on it using bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400262/how-to-run-command-on-ec2-instance-after-starting-session-manager-on-it-using-ba)

Also, delete your API keys and invalidate any still active session tokens you have that have hit sites like this one. Do it now. :D